# Android. How to share result from one fragment to another with fragment result api?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle, android-fragment-manager, activity-result-api

I'm trying to share result from one fragment to another with fragment result api.
Here is my fragment structure:
Activity - container contains: FragmentA, FragmentB, FragmentC.

At the same time FragmentA also contains FragmentA1 (FragmentA.childFragmentManager.fragments = FragmentA1)

And now I need to share result from FragmentC to FragmentA1.

My code inside FragmentC:

```
 setFragmentResult(
                                requestKey = REQUEST_KEY,
                                result = bundleOf(
                                    RESULT_CATEGORY_ID to it.id,
                                ),
                            )
```

My code inside fragmentA1 inside onCreate:

```
 setFragmentResultListener(
            FragmentC.REQUEST_KEY,
        ) { _, bundle ->
          // handle result 
        }
```

The problem is that this handler is never called and I don't get any result.

Is it possible to fix this? Or, with such a structure of fragments, it will not be possible to share the result with fragment result api.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of this particular result API in this scenario, but seems like a sharedViewModel/repository could better serve you in these scenarios with less coupling between fragments. In short, the result from FragmentC should be made available to FragmentA1 without any knowledge of each other. FragmentC makes the data available, A1 is observing a Flow or similar and picks the new value right away.